# Twitter App in Processing

Tags: api, twitter, processing

I'm having a massive problem with a Twitter App I'm trying to create. I've been at this problem for 2 weeks straight, 14 hours a day and I cannot get my head around how to fix. I'm a newbie so I'm sure it's just a simple matter.

I need my twitter stream to display five tweets at a time. Then I need for it to remove the oldest tweet and replace it with a new one. Now I was told the best method for this is to use the Linkedlist, which makes perfect sense. However, whenever I attempt to incorporate this, it just won't work.

If someone could help me out I'd be endlessly grateful as I'm at my wits end at this point.

Here's the code:

```
import com.francisli.processing.http.*;

import java.util.LinkedList;

//LinkedList myList;


HashMap overall = new HashMap();


HttpClient client;

LinkedList myList;



PImage prhomoPix;

int results_to_show = 5;
int updateTime = 10000;
int updateDiff = 0;



void setup()
{

 myList = new LinkedList();
 for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
 {
   myList.add(client);
 }

  size(1143, 800);



  prhomoPix = loadImage("PrhomoAppBg.jpg");

  background(0);
  image(prhomoPix, 0, 0);


  fill(0, 0, 0, 80);
  noStroke();
  rect(20, 135, 370, 670);

  fill(0, 0, 0, 80);
  noStroke();
  rect(755, 135, 370, 670);

  textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);

}






void responseReceived(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response)
{


 if(response.statusCode == 200)
 {

    JSONObject allresults;
    allresults = response.getContentAsJSONObject();
    //JSONObject timeline_tweets = response.getContentAsJSONObject();






  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
 {

    text(allresults.get("results").get(i).get("text").stringValue(), 25, 50+(i*120), 330, 330);

  }
  frameRate(2);




//}



   //for (int i=0; i < results_to_show; i++)
  //{

  // text(allresults.get("results").get(i).get("text").stringValue(), 25, 50+(i*120), 330, 330);
 // }

}

      else
  {
    text("UH-OH" + response.getContentAsString(), 50, 50);
  } 
}


void tweetUpdate()
{

  if(millis() > (updateTime + updateDiff))
  {


    client = new HttpClient(this, "search.twitter.com");//what webservice we are using, this is the priate OAuth one. "this" means it is not cpying setting from anywhere else
    client.GET("search.json?q=dublin&rpp="+results_to_show+"&result_type=recent");





    //println(myList);

    updateDiff = millis();

  }  

 }




   void draw()
{
 myList.remove(client);
 myList.add(client);
 tweetUpdate(); 

}
```

Once again thanks so much!

Comment: If you have actually spent ~200 hours on this, you should probably ask for help earlier next time. You will be much more productive.

Comment: I have already, which is where i got the linklist from. I only discovered this site recently.

Comment: Also, sorry to bother everyone with this question. I wouldn't take up forum space unless I was 100% certain I was stuck

Answer (score 0):

To be honest with you, Java is really not my field, but these tutorials looked quite self explanatory. Hope they help.

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/linkedlist/

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to repaint whole screen in `draw()` method.
2. I guess, people told you to save **tweets** in `LinkedList`, not `HttpClient`.
3. Update list of tweets in `responseReceived()` method.

Eventually, your draw would look something like this:

```
void draw() {
  // repaint
  background(0);
  // draw picture
  image(prhomoPix, 0, 0);
  // repaint all tweets
  for(int i=0; i< tweetsList.size(); ++i {
    drawTweet(tweetsList);
  }
  tweetUpdate(); // update list of tweets from server
}
```

`tweetUpdate()`

```
void tweetUpdate() {
    client = new HttpClient(this, "search.twitter.com");
    client.GET("search.json?q=dublin&rpp="+results_to_show+"&result_type=recent");
}
```